# How can i select text in javascript Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am not able to select text which i retrieve from directoryScanner.php file into the div container. So what ever gets displayed in div container , i cannot select it by mouse.

```html
 <div id="file_link_panel">
 </div>
```

Following javascript code

```js
function dirRefresher(){
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST","directoryScanner.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajax.readyState ==4 & ajax.status == 200){
            msg = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById("file_link_panel").innerHTML = msg;
        }
    }
    ajax.send();
}
setInterval(dirRefresher,1000);
```

And this simple php script named directoryScanner.php

```
<?php
echo "kunal";
echo "pankaj"; 
echo "shekhar";
?>
```

Comment: select text means what? Unclear what you are asking

Comment: What do you mean "select text" ?

Comment: My guess is the fact you are rewriting the DOM every second and that is locking up the page. And hopefully your server is fast enough to respond and you have zero network traffic

Comment: i mean what ever content i retrive from php file by ajax in the div container. I cannot select the retrived content by right clicking mouse button.

Comment: totally logic... how you want to select a text that change every 1 second ?

Comment: Can't understand your question clear.
you mean... 
document.getElementById("file_link_panel").innerHTML = msg; this is not working sometimes?

Comment: @pankajroy And that is because you are doing a crazy about of updates to the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are making tons of Ajax calls and updating the element over and over again so as you try to make the selection, it is being replaced. You are better off increasing the timeout and only firing the next one after you get the call back from the server. Also there is no need to replace the html, if the content is the same.

```
function dirRefresher(){
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST","directoryScanner.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajax.readyState ==4 & ajax.status == 200){
            var msg = this.responseText;
            var elem = document.getElementById("file_link_panel");
            if(elem.innerHTML !== msg) {
              elem.innerHTML = msg;
            }
            setTimeout(dirRefresher, 5000);
        }
    }
    ajax.send();
}

dirRefresher()
```

If you need quicker updates, you should be looking into webSockets, not Ajax.

Comment: how can i get the call back from the server , and the fire the function?

Comment: fire what function?

Comment: you said "only firing the next one after you get the call back from the server", how do i do what you just said?

Comment: what happens if i change 5000 to 1000 ? Will i be able to select the text?

Comment: I do not know and you realize your server is going to hate you right?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `innerText` besides `innerHTML`:
You return from php just text so you need to include `innerText`. Like so:

```
function dirRefresher(){
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST","directoryScanner.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajax.readyState ==4 & ajax.status == 200){
            msg = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById("file_link_panel").innerText= msg;
        }
    }
    ajax.send();
}
setInterval(dirRefresher,1000);
```

Comment: How would that make any difference?

Comment: php return just text without html tags. innerHTML interpreted the text as html format, so i think that it needs to change the innerHTML to innerText.

Comment: Still unclear how that would prevent the user from being about to copy text with their mouse.

Comment: I think that would prevent the user from being about to copy text, because as i mentioned above, php return just text without html tags. So ajax waits to grab just text as a response.

Comment: since the content from php file is retrieved  so frequently (in 1 second interval) , so div is getting updated every second and thus not letting anything in the div to get coppied from mouse.